# Sentry Cli - A proguard mapping file was missing

Tags: android, sentry

I am uploading proguard mapping.txt file on sentry using sentry cli (command below). File is getting uploaded but when I check the crash on sentry it gives this error - *A proguard mapping file was missing. Mapping Uuid 4c7f8cfc-6f45-48d2-9beb-cf4292e50f19*

Also the mapping uid given on sentry cli is different compared to generated uuid in sentry-debug-meta.properties

> sentry-cli --url http://x.x.x.x:9000 --auth-token xxxxxx
> upload-proguard --org sentry --project myproject --write-properties
> MYPATH/android/app/build/generated/assets/sentry/playstoreRelease/sentry-debug-meta.properties
> MYPATH/android/app/build/outputs/mapping/playstoreRelease/mapping.txt
> --log-level debug

Comment: give it a try to the Sentry Android Gradle Plugin, https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/proguard/
since the generated UUID should be set to the event before being sent to Sentry, the plugin does that automatically for you.

Comment: @ManoelNeto i need to use sentry-cli only. Can't go with this approach